# full image without stretch or repeat with high quality pixel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

how can i put a full background image without stretch or repeat the image with high quality pixel i don't want image look like stretching image

html code

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill fill" style="background-image:url('img/intro%205.jpg');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>P-DECO</h1>
                <p>YOUR   PARTNER   TO   THE   TOP </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div></div>
```

css code:

```
.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height:300px;
    background-position:center ;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;background-origin: content-box;
    z-index: 1030;
    position: fixed; 
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? What size is your image and what problem are you facing? Generally, if you don't do any resizing of your background image (don't use `background-size`), it will be pixel perfect (but of course it has to be big enough, and you will see a different area on different computers and screens.)

Comment: 1024*620 the problem if i remove size the image will be center in the middle with white on each side and if i put size the image will be stretched and it didn't look good i want to the image appear totally width and height and look good not look stretched in all device

Comment: Ah, so you want to resize the image, but preserve the aspect ratio (the ratio between width and height). Huy's answer should address that. Of course, there will always be some blurring when enlarging the image. That's just the way it is - the computer can't show clean pixels that it doesn't have. For that to look perfect, you'd need a larger image

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
background-size: cover;
```

If you want to have background cover all over the element, then I think it's the solution.

> how can i put a full background image without stretch or repeat the image with high quality pixel i don't want image look like stretching image.

I think it's possible when your image size is larger than your element size.